# Duplicate content issue for many pages

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, duplicates

I have many pages with the following structure `..component/extension/page`

I need to redirect all of these pages to the correct structure `..browse/page`

I'm certain this can be done inside .htaccess. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^component/extension/(.*)$ /browse/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I hope this doesn't throw up any curveballs in regards to SEO.